.NET 4.8 HttpClient throws ArgumentException: only http or https schemas allowed
I am trying to call a web service with HttpClient, same as always:
await client.GetAsync("https://example.com/path/to/resource/123");

However, with this particular service I am running into an

ArgumentException: only 'http' and 'https' schemas are allowed.
at System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.set_RequestUri(Uri value)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateResponseMessage(HttpWebResponse webResponse, HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
...

Looking at the response headers in the browser debugger, the response has the content-location header returned as resource://example/123, which of course is neither http nor https.
This service works fine in every other browser/client I've tried; the .NET 8.0 HttpClient works.
It is only .NET Framework that is unable to handle this.
I tried adding in a custom handler in the HttpClient pipeline, but the exception happens before it reaches my custom handler.
I also tried switching the DefaultRequestHandler to WebRequestHandler to no avail.
Is there a way to intercept the response headers before the HttpResponseMessage gets created?
Or is .NET 4.8 just completely unable to handle non-http responses?

After trying everything I could think of, I abandoned HttpClient on .NET Framework and implement everything via WebRequest.Create.  Feels dirty, but at least it works.
